# How can I have my passport chip scanned properly?

Tags: uk

I am applying for a BNO visa and the uk immigration ID check app requests to scan my passport chip. I used the demo app ReadID to check my passport chip and everything was ok, the chip could be scanned and information could be read. However, when I tried to scan my passport chip through the uk immigration app, something went wrong and I got locked 24 hours for trying a few times. The same thing happened for three days already. I tried to withdraw my application and reapply, but I was still locked. Can someone help to solve my problem? It is quite sure that there is nothing wrong with my passport chip but I could not understand why the uk immigration ID check app could not read my passport chip. In fact, it did locate my passport chip as there was vibration but once it started to read, it jumped out immediately. Should I try to withdraw and reapply? Will the scanning work for the new application? Or should I renew my passport again which is already a new one?

Comment: This looks like a technical problem that should be directed to the UKVI system support team https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/using-the-uk-immigration-id-check-app

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can only be definitively answered by the UKVI help centre